# Trans dip stick reads same hot and cold is that normal

Tags: transmission

I check the trany fluid yesterday when van was in nuetral and warm the today checked it before starting it up and it at the same level is that normal

Comment: Are you sure the trans fluid was hot?

Comment: Is checking in neutral the correct method?

Comment: I never knew an AT that the fluid level was checked without starting the engine; This is required to fill the torque converter on any AT that I am familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

With a automatic transmission equipped with a dip stick most manufacturers recommended
procedure is first.
Drive vehicle few miles bring tranmission fluid normal operating temperature.
Stop set hand brake put tranmission into park.
Remove dipstick wipe off reinsert back into travsmission.
With engine idling step on brake pedal and cycle through gears from 1st back to park
pausing in each gear for 5 seconds.
With engine still on remove dip stick wipe off reinsert now remove and make sure fluid 
is within the hash marks on dip stick.

Answer (score 0):

Checking in park with engine idling is the proper procedure.  Go out to the car when it's been sitting overnight and just turn it on and check.  A few miles of city driving should warm it up - stopping and taking off creates more heat than cruising.  Wait until your temp gauge is at normal operating temp then check again.  Transmission fluid definitely expands when it's hot so what you are describing is strange.